# Creating Gradual Text Using Paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text

I'm trying to create a gradual text the follow a path using Inkscape. I know it can be done using Illustrator (see image bellow), but I can't figure it out using Inkscape.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the 'Envelope Deformation LPE' and the 'Bend LPE', in that order.

1. Type text.
2. Path > Union (does not work in the beta of 1.0 currently, use Path > Object to path -> Ungroup -> Path > Combine instead.)
3. Path > Path effects
4. +
5. Envelope Deformation LPE
6. Switch to node tool
7. Edit top path / bottom path to increase thickness in the middle
8. +
9. Bend
10. Edit on-canvas

Result:

[image]